# Is my bluetooth working right?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, dell-latitude

I'm not sure if Bluetooth is working right on my dell latitude d630. I bought it used with Windows 7 professional installed. I am sure it has Bluetooth, but when I try to add the device it just says scanning for devices for about 5 minutes (it would go longer if I didn't cancel it) and it never finds my device (which I am sure I turned on correctly). Can anybody tell me how to fix this? I took instructions from eHow on checking if your computer has Bluetooth, and it showed that my computer has Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make your device "discoverable" or "visible" before your computer can pair with it. Check with the manufacturer of whatever this blue tooth thing this is on how to do that.

You might also check your Windows "Device Manager" to make sure there are no driver problems with your blue tooth adapter (inside the computer) too.