# Bluetooth enabled and "working correctly" but not finding any devices

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a **HP Pavilion dv7 6051ei notebook** running **Windows 7 Professional 64bit** . And, as the title states. I switch on bluetooth and enable it, but when I scan for devices, it doesn't find anything. I have another machine which finds the other bluetooth devices easily.

Also for instance my android phone picks up the hp laptop, but not vice versa, the laptop doesn't find anything.

Anybody that might be able to help with this? Please just ask if more info is needed.

Thanks in advance!

PS - I don't really want to do this because it's rather tedious. But might it help removing the actual  bluetooth component in the notebook and just putting it back again?

Comment: Did you set the other devices to discoverable? (Blue tooth has 3 modes: Off, on, and on and detectable for other devices. The defaults on most devices require you to explicitly set them to discoverable).

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/448727/is-my-bluetooth-working-right

Comment: @Hennes - The device in particular that I want to add is a mouse. I'm not too sure if one can set it to irrecoverable?

Comment: Also the mouse and my phone and so on gets picked up with the other machine. It's just my HP notebook that doesn't find anything?

Answer (score 2):

Switch your wifi adapter off and try bluetooth search again..

I'm having an issue with my own Intel Wifi + Bluetooth card on Windows 7 64-bit, when I connect my phone with Wifi on, then it's not working properly, it won't connect.

Comment: Nope didn't work.. Any reason you thought this might solve the problem?

Comment: Just that im having an issue with my own intel wifi+bluetooth card on windows 7 64bit, when I connect my phone with wifi on, than it's not working properly, it won't connect.

Answer (score 2):

Today I upgraded my Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 in my dell inspiron and there are many great features and new apps. But the old issue of Bluetooth problem in windows 8 is not solved by upgrading windows 8 to windows 8.1. But don’t worry, because after working hard and using my tricks on the major issue of Bluetooth in windows 8, today I solved Bluetooth problem in windows 8.1. So now you all can solve Bluetooth issue with the help of my trick.
Bluetooth Problem In Windows 8.1

There are unusual Bluetooth problem in windows 8.1. In Windows 8.1 my Bluetooth mouse, keyboard and headphones were already paired but not able to connect. The blue tooth device connect my wireless Bluetooth devices for few Seconds and then disconnect and searching again and again. My Bluetooth device disconnect again and again and Shows a Error “The btvstack could not be started”. So follow below steps to solve this problem. [tested in dell inspiron and working for all dell laptops].

FIX: Bluetooth Not Working In Windows 8.1

1. → Go to RUN (Windows Logo + R) and type `services.msc` and Enter.
2. → Now find “Bluetooth Support Service” and double click on it.
3. → In General Tab change startup type Manual to Automatic.
4. → Now click on Log On Tab and mark on “This Account” and type your account name or browse to find your account name.
5. → Now remove both hidden password and restart your PC.
6. → Now Re install your Bluetooth drivers. You can download latest Bluetooth drivers from your PC official website.
7. → If Bluetooth drivers not compatible with Windows 8.1 then follow simple steps.

   a. → Go to RUN(Windows logo + R) and type `regedit` to open registry editor.

   b. → In registry editor go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion`

   c. → In Current Version find Current version and change the value 6.3 to 6.2.

Answer (score 2):

Dean,

As Hennes stated, bluetooth devices usually need to be set to discoverable before they can be found by other devices. You mention that the bluetooth device in question is a mouse.

I have found that devices without screens can usually be put in discoverable mode by powering it off, then pressing and **holding the power button until** an led, optical laser in your case, **starts flashing** which would indicate discovery mode is on. At that point, you should search for devices on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I was plugged in to a Dell docking station, unplugging and plugging solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

> I have the same problem with my HP Pavilion DV7-6051ea. Device Manager
>   shows that Bluetooth is working fine but it won't open the settings
>   page or find any device. Even my phone will not find my laptop. Did
>   you fix your problem?

I have just found an aswer for my problem so maybe it will help you as well. I just checked my services and "Bluetooth Service" was enabled. On windows type "msconfig" in search field at the start menu and open MSconfig. Go to the Services Tab and search for services related to Bluetooth. If any of them are unchecked they will not load on Windows start so make sure you have checked them